# StackOverflowError loading a FXML file

Tags: controller, javafx, fxml

Hello everyone I get always an error by loading a fxml file via FXMLLoader. I got this classes:

```
package mediabox.app.model;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import mediabox.app.controller.Controller;

/**
 * Objekte diser Klasse repräsentieren Fenster
 * @author Christian
 */
public class Window {

    private final Stage stage;

    /**
     * 
     * @param resourceURL Pfad der zu ladenden FXML Datei
     * @param controller Controller des Fensters
     * @param height Höhe des Fensters
     * @param width  Breite des Fensters
     * @param resizable Gibt an ob das Fenster maximierbar sein soll
     * @param fullscreen Gibt an ob das Fenster als Vollbild geöffnet wird
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Window(String resourceURL, Controller controller, int height, int width, boolean resizable, boolean fullscreen) throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resourceURL)); //Lädt die zugehörige FXML
        loader.setController(controller);
        Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, height, width);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(resizable);
        stage.setFullScreen(fullscreen);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }


    /**
     * Zeigt das Fenster
     */
    public void show(){
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Versteckt das Fenster
     */
    public void hide(){
        stage.hide();
    }
}
```

This is my window class.

```
        package mediabox.app.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import mediabox.app.model.DatabaseConnector;
import mediabox.app.model.Music;
import mediabox.app.model.Window;
import mediabox.app.model.exceptions.ConnectionException;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 * Diese Klasse repräsentiert den MusicscreenController. Er steuert alle Aktion
 * die auf auf dem Musicscreen getätigt werden. D.h auch die Aktionen die
 * innerhalb der Tabelle(Datenbank) und der Playlist ausgeführt werden.
 * @author Christian
 */
public final class MusicscreenController extends Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private VBox box;

    //@FXML private Node playlistNode;
    @FXML private final TableView libraryNode;
    @FXML private MediaView mediaPlayerView;


    private final Window musicscreen;

    public MusicscreenController() throws IOException {
        musicscreen = new Window("/mediabox/app/view/MusicscreenView.fxml", this, 0, 0, false, true);
        musicscreen.show();
        libraryNode = new TableView();
        initLibrary();
        libraryNode.requestFocus();
        libraryNode.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    }

    /**
     * Initialisiert die Bibliothek
     */
    @Override
    protected void initLibrary(){
        try {
            DatabaseConnector.connectTo("src/mediabox/database/database");
            libraryNode.getItems().addAll(DatabaseConnector.loadEntries("Music")); // Einträge der Datenbank 
                                                                            // auslesen und der library Node hinzufügen 
        } catch (SQLException | ConnectionException | NamingException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MusicscreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }


    @FXML
    public void onLibraryRequest(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
            try {
                MediaPlayerController mediaPlayerController = new MediaPlayerController((Music)libraryNode.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MusicscreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

This is my Controller class.

I can't find any eroor in this code. For a few days the code works fine ....

-GhostfaceChilla-

Answer (score 0):

When you load the FXML, the FXML loader sees the `fx:controller="mediabox.app.controller.MusicscreenController"` attribute in the root element. This instructs it to instantiate a `new MusciscreenController`. The `MusicscreenController`'s constructor calls the `Window` constructor. The `Window` constructor creates a new `FXMLLoader` and calls its `load()` method, which parses the FXML, causing it to create a new `MusicscreenController`.

So you have infinite recursion.

You probably just need to remove the constructor from the controller entirely, and place most of the logic from there in the `initialize()` method:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   initLibrary();
    libraryNode.requestFocus();
    libraryNode.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
}
```

You cannot really show the window from the controller, as both the constructor and `initialize` method are guaranteed to complete before you get a chance to add the root node from the FXML to a `Scene`. (Additionally, you want your FXML-Controller pair to be flexible enough to be able to be used when they are not the root of a `Scene`.)

So you should either just invoke `show()` from the `Window` constructor, or you should invoke it from wherever you invoke the `Window` constructor.